# git fsck --full not working

Tags: git, puppet

When trying to "git pull", I'm receiving the following:

remote: fatal: object f72e5435f64db2f7565773548c94ab6779fb96a6 is corrupted
error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.
fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: protocol error: bad pack header

I've since tried the following:

$ git fsck --full 2e9920dc5a23c ; git repack
fatal: object 2e9920dc5a23cc2afff46348642398f6d9f6f47e is corrupted
fatal: object f72e5435f64db2f7565773548c94ab6779fb96a6 is corrupted

$ git fsck --full
fatal: object 2e9920dc5a23cc2afff46348642398f6d9f6f47e is corrupted

Any ideas please on how to resolve the corruption?  (This is on Linux OELv6 if it helps).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself, turned out it was a file ownership issue.  Ran "chown -R git * " from the correct location and now its all working...